# Visa, Mastercard and Boleto with Magento (Brazil Payments)

Tags: payment, payment-gateway

Is there a secure and open source (or free) Magento module to take payments via Visa, Mastercard cards and Boleto, for Brazil?

Comment: There are a lot of free and open source modules, for example payone or ogone. But the fees are not for the modules, they are for the payments. And there is a CC payment module in magento included ("Saved CC") but I never used it.

Comment: The Saved CC payment method is for saving the customers credit card number in plain text in an order.  That's a big security risk.  Please don't use that one!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at below extensions

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/boleto-bancario-brasil.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/adyen-payment.html

Comment: Very good extensions. I will take a look and return. Thx. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this module:

http://r-martins.github.io/PagSeguro-Magento-Transparente/download.html

According to the module description:

> This extensions allows your store to acept payments using credit cards with PagSeguro without needing to redirect customer to Pagseguro's website. To use PagSeguro Transparente you should require authorization of PagSeguro UOL. You can find more details at official website.